# JavaScript quirks - window

Tags: javascript, window, key, global-variables

I just executed the following code block in Firefox Developer Edition 49.0a2 (2016-06-17)

```
let array1 = Object.keys(window);

let array2 = [];
for (let key in window) {
    array2.push(key);
};

/* filter for keys missing in Object.keys(window) */
array2.filter(function (e) {
   return !array1.includes(e); 
}).toString();

//result:
//"addEventListener,dispatchEvent,removeEventListener"
```

The reason for this difference is that these are no own properties of `window` as can be checked using `window.hasOwnProperty(...)`. What I don't understand is: Where are they from then, because I can access them by `window.addEventListener` etc. And why are things like `eval` and `keys` not in that list?

Btw: What is the difference between `keys` and `Object.keys` anyways? Because
`Object.keys(window).toString() === keys(window).toString() //true`

Comment: The event listener methods (in Firefox anyway) are inherited from the `EventTarget` interface, so they're not "own" properties.

Comment: I got 99 problems but `prototype` 'aint one.

Comment: @ndugger Would you please explain what the window's prototype has to do with that? Because I don't get it.